# In principle, what is the relation between Artifical Intelligence and Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, artificial-intelligence, computation-models

I am working on my cs project about AI & Turing machines, so i know that [Artifical Intelligence](http://www.alanturing.net/turing_archive/pages/reference%20articles/what%20is%20ai.html) is meant to implement different algorithms into the machine {the computer} to solve a problem or a set of problems together and i am getting AI as: (the machine is 'programmed' on a certain algorithms to solve problems or to show intelligent behavior when solving a specific problem).

> Artifical Intelligence is usually defined as the science of making computers do things that require intelligence when done by humans.

On the other hand, [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) just manipulates data of {0 & 1} on a tape according to a table of rules to solve a problem {calculate the input}.

> A Turing machine is an abstract machine that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules.

So, generally speaking both AI and Turing machines are meant to compute the input and transfer it to a right answer {output} so here is what iam confused about :

1. What a formal defination would relate both of them ?
2. Can i say that both algorithms of AI and a table of rules of a
   Turing machine are the same ?
3. Can i also say that AI is about choosing the best solution between
   different solutions to the input and turing machine just
   shows a solution of the input ?

Comment: Why do you think there's any particular relationship between the two?

Comment: The Turing Test was thought up by the same guy who thought up the Turing Machine.   Frankly that's about it.

Comment: @tjd ya thats makes sense, @ DR  the answer is just under which perfectly clarified what i wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turing machines are a model of computation, one way of formally defining the concept of an *algorithm*. While Turing machines are usually defined using barebones input/output capabilities, it is not difficult to extend them so that they can apply to the kind of problems that AI is after.

The relation between AI and Turing machines is thus:

> Artificial intelligence is implemented by algorithms. Algorithms can be described by Turing machines.

Note, however, that Turing machines are not a great model for describing practical algorithms, since they work rather differently than actual machines, and as a consequence the *complexity* of algorithms is somewhat different when implemented in Turing machines compared to their real-world implementations. You should replace Turing machines with your favorite programming language.

Now I can answer your actual questions:

1) *What a formal definition would relate both of them?* Artificial intelligence is not a formal concept, so none.

2) *Can I say that both algorithms of AI and a table of rules of a Turing machine are the same?* Artificial intelligence is about algorithms performing some tasks, and Turing machines are a way of describing algorithms. So the answer to this question is positive.

3) *Can I also say that AI is about choosing the best solution between different solutions to the input and Turing machine just shows a [sic] solution of the input?* No, this is a false dichotomy. Algorithms implementing AI and algorithms implemented on Turing machines (with I/O) are exactly the same. There is absolutely no difference. Also, there is no such thing as a "best solution". So the answer to this question is negative.